# Setting tablePerHierachy to False breaks dynamic finders

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 2.2.2

Let assume, there are two Domains

```
class Rule{
  String label

  static mapping = {
    tablePerHierarchy false
  } 
}

class RuleVersion extends Rule{
  String state
  Rule reference
  User author //another Domain
}
```

Then a simple finder like:`Rule.findByLabel("foo")` produces an error.

```
ERROR   org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:   Unknown column 'this_.col_author_id' in 'field list'
```

It seems that GORM creates a sql statement, which contains also the columns of the RuleVersion Domain, which are due to `tablePerHierarchy false` not defined in Rule Table.

Is this a bug in GORM or am I missing something?